# How to get span text inside onclick popup - jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dom, text

I have a question:

```
<span class="item-link item-caption" id="qitem_6093500" onclick="return overlib('    <table cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot;><tr><td style=&quot;vertical-align: top;&quot;><table cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; class=&quot;itemImagesContainer&quot;><tr><td colspan=&quot;2&quot;><div class=&quot;itemMainImageContainer&quot; style=&quot;background: url(\'gfx/gothic/items/krotkilukdmt8.jpg\') no-repeat left;&quot;></div></td></tr></table></td><td class=&quot;item-desc itemDescContainer&quot;><div><b><i>Broń dystansowa dwuręczna (lekka)</i></b></div><div class=&quot;itemdesc-s&quot;><b>Obrażenia: <span class=incstat>27</span> - <span class=incstat>33</span></b></div><div class=&quot;itemdesc-s itemEffectsList&quot;>trafienie <b>+5</b><br />ilość ataków na rundę: <b>3</b></div><div class=&quot;itemdesc-s&quot;><b>Wymagania:</b> POZIOM: 2 (4), WIEDZA: 6 (12)</div><div class=&quot;itemdesc-s&quot;><div><b>Cena sprzedaży:</b> <span >900 PLN</span></div></div><div class=&quot;itemDescDetailsContainer&quot;><div class=&quot;itemDescDetailsLink&quot;><a href=&quot;test_items.php?class=1&amp;baseType=68&amp;prefix=0&amp;sufix=0&amp;legendary=0&amp;playerLvl=128&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;><img src=&quot;gfx/lhx/msg1.gif&quot;/></a></div><div class=&quot;itemDescDetailsLink&quot;><a href=&quot;?a=auction&amp;do=closed&amp;itemType=0&amp;itemClass=1&amp;prefix=0&amp;suffix=0&amp;legend=0&amp;withoff=0&amp;onlyMine=0&amp;t=10&amp;tab=99&quot;><img src=&quot;gfx/aumakebid.gif&quot;/></a></div></div></td></tr></table>',CAPTIONFONTCLASS,'item-caption item-caption2',CLOSEFONTCLASS,'item-close',TEXTFONTCLASS,'item-desc',STICKY,CLOSECLICK,CLOSETEXT,'ZAMKNIJ',CAPTION,'Dobry Krótki łuk',HAUTO,WIDTH,550);">Dobry Krótki łuk</span>
```

How can I get inside this and get text from `<span >900 PLN</span>`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is very strange. There may be some limitations that you are not able to control but if you really have to you can do this. I would not recommend this because the data may not be able to parsed in this fashion consistently.

First, the data inside your onClick seems like it is probably dynamic, meaning it may not always be in the same format. Here for example we grabbed all of the parameters being submitted to the overlib() and try to split on the commas to get a list of parameters. In this case there is a comma in your 1st parameter so we have to add the first 2 parameters together to get the actual first parameter after splitting.

Second, this uses a selector in the html from the 1st parameter as 'div.itemdesc-s span:last()'. This span has no unique identifiers so it may or may not always be the last span in that div.

If at all possible try to obtain the value in a different way because this is very likely to break under different scenarios with dynamic data being inserted into the onClick attribute. You could get lucky but I would recommend trying a different approach.

```js
var onClickValue = $('#qitem_6093500').attr('onclick');
var parameters = onClickValue.substring(16, onClickValue.length - 2).split(',');
var html = $.parseHTML(parameters[0] + parameters[1]);
$('.myValue').text($(html).find('div.itemdesc-s span:last()').text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="item-link item-caption" id="qitem_6093500" onclick="return overlib('    <table cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot;><tr><td style=&quot;vertical-align: top;&quot;><table cellspacing=&quot;0&quot; cellpadding=&quot;0&quot; class=&quot;itemImagesContainer&quot;><tr><td colspan=&quot;2&quot;><div class=&quot;itemMainImageContainer&quot; style=&quot;background: url(\'gfx/gothic/items/krotkilukdmt8.jpg\') no-repeat left;&quot;></div></td></tr></table></td><td class=&quot;item-desc itemDescContainer&quot;><div><b><i>Broń dystansowa dwuręczna (lekka)</i></b></div><div class=&quot;itemdesc-s&quot;><b>Obrażenia: <span class=incstat>27</span> - <span class=incstat>33</span></b></div><div class=&quot;itemdesc-s itemEffectsList&quot;>trafienie <b>+5</b><br />ilość ataków na rundę: <b>3</b></div><div class=&quot;itemdesc-s&quot;><b>Wymagania:</b> POZIOM: 2 (4), WIEDZA: 6 (12)</div><div class=&quot;itemdesc-s&quot;><div><b>Cena sprzedaży:</b> <span >900 PLN</span></div></div><div class=&quot;itemDescDetailsContainer&quot;><div class=&quot;itemDescDetailsLink&quot;><a href=&quot;test_items.php?class=1&amp;baseType=68&amp;prefix=0&amp;sufix=0&amp;legendary=0&amp;playerLvl=128&quot; target=&quot;_blank&quot;><img src=&quot;gfx/lhx/msg1.gif&quot;/></a></div><div class=&quot;itemDescDetailsLink&quot;><a href=&quot;?a=auction&amp;do=closed&amp;itemType=0&amp;itemClass=1&amp;prefix=0&amp;suffix=0&amp;legend=0&amp;withoff=0&amp;onlyMine=0&amp;t=10&amp;tab=99&quot;><img src=&quot;gfx/aumakebid.gif&quot;/></a></div></div></td></tr></table>',CAPTIONFONTCLASS,'item-caption item-caption2',CLOSEFONTCLASS,'item-close',TEXTFONTCLASS,'item-desc',STICKY,CLOSECLICK,CLOSETEXT,'ZAMKNIJ',CAPTION,'Dobry Krótki łuk',HAUTO,WIDTH,550);">Dobry Krótki łuk</span>

<h3>My Value</h3>
<div class="myValue"></div>
```

Comment: I have an item with a certain value, but the value is displayed only after clicking on this item (on popup). I would like to create a script to count the cost of all my items that I have. If I understand the code correctly, you cut out the part and replace it with html to get the value I need. I did not think about it!

Comment: Good luck! I hope you are able to accomplish what you are looking for.

Comment: Sometimes '<div class=&quot;itemdesc-s&quot;><b>Wymagania:</b> POZIOM: 2 (4), WIEDZA: 6 (12)</div>' this is longer and makes array bigger. After that I can't find span becouse <table> isn't closed and can't parse it to html. How can I make it universal?
I mean script can't do `$.parseHTML(parameters[0] + parameters[1]);` I need to: `$.parseHTML(parameters[0] + parameters[1] + parameters[2]);` or even `$.parseHTML(parameters[0] + parameters[1] + parameters[2] + parameters[3]);`